# Remove rows with infinity and certain values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf`. I want to get rid of rows that have infinity or values above 50 and get the result.

mydf

```
s.no       A     B       C       
1         Inf     Inf      999.9
2         0.43    30       23
3         34     22       233           
4         3       43       45
```

result

```
s.no        A     B       C       
2         0.43    30       23
4         3       43       45
```

Comment: Why is there a D column? Is 's.no A' one column name? Also, there are so many solutions out there. Is there anything that you have already tried?

Comment: Could do something like `mydf[!(rowSums((mydf== "Inf") | (mydf> 50))),]` though I'm neither sure if `s.no A` a column and if it should be included in the calculations