# Removing certain values from the dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am not sure how I can do this, but what I need is I need to form a cluster of this dataframe `mydf` where I want to omit the `inf`(infitive) values and the values greater than 50. I need to get the table that has no `inf` and no values greater than 50. How can I get a table that contains no `inf` and no value greater than 50(may be by nullifying those cells)?  However, For clustering part, I don't have any problem because I can do this using mfuzz package. So the only problem I have is that I want to scale the cluster within 0-50 margin.

mydf

```
   s.no       A        B       C       
    1         Inf     Inf      999.9
    2         0.43    30       23
    3         34      22       233           
    4         3       43       45
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove rows with infinity and certain values in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201366/remove-rows-with-infinity-and-certain-values-in-r)

Comment: @Pascal Not a duplicate, I posted that question earlier today. This is something different.

Comment: What's different about this one?  You seem to be asking for the same thing.

Comment: @MAPK: you need to explain how that is not a duplicate. Both appear to be asking to delete rows failing this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NA`, the built in missing data indicator in R:

```
?NA
```

By doing this:

```
mydf[mydf > 50 | mydf == Inf] <- NA
mydf
  s.no     A  B  C
1    1    NA NA NA
2    2  0.43 30 23
3    3 34.00 22 NA
4    4  3.00 43 45
```

Any stuff you do downstream in R should have `NA` handling methods, even if it's just `na.omit`

Comment: `Inf > 50` returns `TRUE` so no need for testing against it. `mydf[mydf > 50] <- NA` will cover it.