# Deleting certain values from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Basically I have a dataframe that looks like this:
mydf

```
            Beg1  Beg2  Beg3  
Pathway1    Sort  AMP   Cool 
Pathway2    Gi    Try   Agt   
Pathway3    AMP   Abor  Myt
```

And I want it to look like this:
revised mydf

```
            Beg1  Beg2  Beg3  
Pathway1    <NA>  AMP   <NA>  
Pathway2    Gi    Try   Agt   
Pathway3    AMP   <NA>  <NA>
```

If it isn't clear, all of the lower case letters are replaced with "NA"'s.  I know that this is very similar to a question ([Removing certain values from the dataframe in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218346/removing-certain-values-from-the-dataframe-in-r)), but the solution given my @jeremycg doesn't work for my data.

Basically, I tried the following things things:
1)

```
mydf[mydf!="AMP" | "Gi" | "Try" | "Agt"] <- NA
```

but I get this error:

```
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

2)

```
mydf[mydf!="AMP" |mydf!="Gi" |mydf!="Try" | mydf!= "Agt"] <- NA
```

But the entire dataframe fills up with "NA"'s

3)

```
for (i in 1:ncol(mydf)){if(mydf!="AMP"|mydf!="Gi"|mydf!="Try"|mydf!="Agt"){<- NA}}
```

but I get this error (repeated a bunch of times)

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

*I don't really know what I am doing

4)

```
mydf[mydf!=("AMP"%in%"Gi"%in%"Try"%in%"AGT")] <- NA
```

but again the whole dataframe fills up with "NA"'s

So, does anyone have any any ideas of how to turn the all of the values that are not equal to "AMP", "Gi", "Try" or "AGT" into "NA"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We loop through the columns of dataset (`lapply(...`), `replace` the values to NA based on creating a logical index with `%in%`

```
v1 <- c("Sort", "Abor", "Cool", "Myt")
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) replace(x, x %in% v1, NA))
mydf
#         Beg1 Beg2 Beg3
#Pathway1 <NA>  AMP <NA>
#Pathway2   Gi  Try  Agt
#Pathway3  AMP <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: @TaylorMaurer  In the original data, what is the condition that you dont want to turn into NA?  Is it all upper case letters?  In that case `mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) replace(x, grepl("[^A-Z]", x), NA))`

Comment: @TaylorMaurer  wouldn't changing the previous code to `ydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) replace(x, grepl("[A-S]", x, invert = TRUE), NA))` work

Comment: is this a fixed match

Comment: i meant the whole string

Comment: @TaylorMaurer  Let me understand, you are replacing Sort with NA because you are matching the whole word or the first letter which is an upper case?

Comment: I am matching the whole word.  The letter and whether it is upper or lowercase is irrelevant to whether it is converted into NA.  If a cells value is not equal to "AMP" "Gi" "Try" or "Agt" it is converted into NA.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the set of values (small case ones) known in advance ? if yes, then you can perhaps apply the iterative replacement (through lookup) suggested earlier. 

if its a unknown set, perhaps you can check the case of the content and then replace. either of the solutions is not perfect, though both should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your second suggestion is quite close to working, there is just some mix up with the Boolean logic. Instead we want to match all values that are not equal to atleast one string. This will look like:

```
mydf[!(mydf=="AMP" | mydf=="Gi" | mydf=="Try" | mydf== "Agt")] <- NA
```

I would also suggest to have a look at the `dplyr` [package](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) for data manipulation tasks, it would then look something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df <-  data.frame(beg1 = c("Sort", "Gi", "AMP"),
                  beg2 = c("AMP",    "Try",   "Abor"),
                  beg3 = c("Cool",   "Agt",  "Myt"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)     

keep_list <- c("AMP", "Gi", "Try", "Agt")

df <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(. %in% keep_list, ., NA)))
```

This will apply the expression in `funs` to all columns, and the dot in the expression references the values in the columns. In this case if the value is in the list of strings to be kept, it will be unchanged, otherwise it will be `NA`.

Comment: This does not seem to work on my larger data set, but instead turns all values but one column into NA and in that one column, doesn't get rid of the things that are not in the list.  Any ideas?